# filter an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

i have an array of objects (Car[] for example) and there is an IsAvailable Property on the object

i want to use the full array  (where IsAvailable is true for some items and false for some others) as the input and return a new array which includes only the items that have IsAvailable = true.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you're using C# 3.0 or better...

```
using System.Linq;

public Car[] Filter(Car[] input)
{
    return input.Where(c => c.IsAvailable).ToArray();
}
```

And if you don't have access to LINQ (you're using an older version of .NET)...

```
public Car[] Filter(Car[] input)
{
    List<Car> availableCars = new List<Car>();

    foreach(Car c in input)
    {
        if(c.IsAvailable)
            availableCars.Add(c);
    }

    return availableCars.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Considering the LINQ implementation is built on IQueryable, how could its implementation be any better than the List based one?

Comment: It's not. I posted it in case the OP was using an older version of .NET. If the OP needs the most performant code, they can at least get the idea from the second example...and optimize it to suit their needs.

Comment: Nope :), still confused... I'm wondering why you are stating performance concerns on the second approach but not on the first... (just nitpicking, I think your solution is great)...

Comment: In the second example, I used a List<T> to store the elements and then output them using the .ToArray() method. I would imagine there has to be a cleaner way to do the work...and I'd hope that if one existed, LINQ to Objects would use it. I'd break out Reflector, but I'm on my Mac at the moment.

Comment: I'll save you the trouble :) Linq to Objects uses essentially an inlined array based list (doesn't use List<T> directly, but performs a standard array doubling algorithm)

Comment: And then copies the result into a new array. So it is essentially the same as your solution above...

Comment: Isn't this answer lacking `using System.Linq;` for the first snippet?

Answer (score 50):

Surprisingly, this question lacks the most natural and efficient answer: [`Array.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=VS.110).aspx)

```
Car[] availableCars = Array.FindAll(cars, c => c.IsAvailable);
```

if it was a `List<Car>` there is also a [`List.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tweaked your intro. No biggie, but I hope I understood you correctly there.

Comment: not sure why, but Array.FindAll does not work with Godot C#. After using system.Linq I was able to filter using ToArray() on collection, and using .Where

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way:

```
Car[] cars = //...
Car[] filtered = cars.Where(c => c.IsAvailable).ToArray();
```

Possibly More Efficient:

```
Car [] cars = //...
    List<Car> filteredList = new List<Car>();
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
    {
        if(cars[i].IsAvailable)
           filteredList.Add(cars[i]);
    }
    Car[] filtered = filteredList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var available = from c in cars where c.IsAvailable == true select c;
```

Or

```
var available = cars.Where(c => c.IsAvailable == true);
```

Comment: Can leave out the explicit comparison against ```true```, ie: ```var available = cars.Where(c => c.IsAvailable);```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a new array, loop through the input array and add only those items which satisfy your conditions to the new array, and return the new array:

```
List<Car> available = new List<Car>();
foreach (Car c in cars) {
    if (c.IsAvailable) {
        available.add(c);
    }
}
//Here you can either just return the list, or create an array from it.
```

Answer (score -12):

an array is filter array when it meets the following conditions:

1. if 9 exists in the list  13 must also exist
2. if 7 exists in the list then 11 must not exist

**solution**

```
int[] a = {7 , 72, 6, 13, 9 };
int i, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0, n = 0;
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 9)
    {
        k = 1;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 13)
    {
        l = 1;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 7)
    {
        m = 1;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 11)
    {
        n= 1;
    }
}
if ((k == 1 && l == 1) && (m == 1 && n == 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("is not filter array");
}
else if (k == 1 && l!= 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("is not filter array");
}
else if (m ==1 && n==1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("is not filter array ");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("is filter array");
Console.WriteLine("the element of an array is:");
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

As i think this code is surely work for if you need to test an array.
 reta seboka ambo universtity woliso campuse department of information TECH.!!

Comment: This is not filtering an array.  This is returning whether certain values are in the array, in a very bad way at that.