# c# array select

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a bool array

```
a[1] = true
a[2] = false
a[3] = true
a[4] = true
```

how do i select only true values to a new array?

Thanks!

Comment: What use do you have for an array only containing several copies of the value `true`?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912128/filter-an-array-in-c). This is kind of a duplicate question.

Comment: @Anon I need the keys for the true values

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter an array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912128/filter-an-array-in-c)

Comment: @Iternity: What is a type of an array a, how it is declared and why do you need to select this?

Comment: @Artur: It's declared like this: `bool[] arrayName;` How do I know? Because that's how you declare arrays in C#. I don't see how this is possibly relevant.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You are wrong. there is no declaration of a in the question. a can be almost anything with overlodable operator [] and type conversion to the class instance

Comment: Incorrect question : "how do i select only true values to a new array?" meant "how do i count only true values to a new array?" thats leads to misunderstanding, unclear meaning and false answers. Shame

Comment: @Artur: Then it wouldn't be a "bool array", as explained in the top line. It would be "some other class, with an overridden `[]` operator and type conversion to `bool`".

Comment: @Cody Gray: Possibly, you shouldn't be so sure that autor understand what he is asking and can understand what about we are talking about in between? And, you are too rely on corectness of input data. That is called idealizm. I'm still thinks that question is unclear of meaning, so untill specified, it still only your guess. You can't be so sure. Right guess on a wrong input is not enouth, At second, it is not quite difficult to write an array type here, anyway. But author didn't write it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't really know why you would want to do this but...

```
bool[] a = {true, false, true, true};
bool[] b = a.Where(x => x).ToArray();
```

If you just want to count how many "true"s there are:

```
int c = a.Count(x => x);
```

Comment: You really don't want to get into the habit of performing a `boolVar == true` check. It's not very good code.

Comment: Its explicit so that the questioner can get a better idea of what is happening and hopefully learn.  And why is it bad to perform this explicit check.  I bet it gets compiled to the exact same thing.

Comment: Indeed, the generated IL is the same for both constructs in C#. But that's not necessarily true for *all* languages. In general, I agree that being explicit is good in your answer, but you might want to add a clarifier that the `== true` part is not necessary. Sometimes, people just copy and paste code they get in answers here into their IDE.

Comment: @AlastairPitts: I don't see any reason to not use the explicit "`boolVar == true` check," other than to save a few keystrokes. If you think that's bad code, perhaps you should indicate why.

Comment: For example, in JavaScript values that would be evaluated a truthy would not pass this equality check. On the other hand, in functional languages where concept of LINQ comes from this check would be a smelly code as well, since it would be more idiomatic to write something like a.Where(Identity), but since the C# hasn't established such function, (x => x) would be in a good proximity.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean a new array containing the indices of 'a' that had a value of true...

```
// Assuming here that a begins at 0, unlike your example...
Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).Where(i=>a[i]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
bool[] result = a.Where(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think this only works in C# 3.0, where lambda expressions were introduced.

Comment: @Timwi: Thanks, I should have been more specific, it works for version of .NET 3.0 and later. ;-)