# Filter array of string and get only matching ones with searched string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of `string` and I want to get back from it a filtered array that contains only those strings that match the searched string.

```
string[] myValues = {"School.Report1", "School.Report2", "School.Report3", "House.Report1", "House.Report2"};
string myFilter = "School";
string[] filteredValues = myValues.Filter(myFilter); // or something similar
```

`filteredValues` must contains only: `"School.Report1", "School.Report2", "School.Report3"`.

**-- EDIT --**

I prefer a non-LINQ approach if possibile. Otherwise I know that this question can be answered with the solution proposed here: [filter an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912128/filter-an-array-in-c-sharp).

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter an array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912128/filter-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Sayse Yes, but the proposed solution that doesn't use LINQ, is a `foreach` loop with the comparison inside. I want to know if there's a more elegant and concise way to do it without LINQ.

Comment: Can it contain `School1.Report1`

Comment: @CheshireCat: You haven't mentioned that you can't use LINQ, why?

Comment: You should show what you have tried, that was just the first duplicate I found but there are plenty of duplicates around. and most of them use the method you described so I'm not sure what the actual question is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use LINQ you can still use [`Array.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
string[] filteredValues = Array.FindAll(myValues, s => s.Contains(myFilter));
```

or maybe you want to keep only all strings which first token(separated by dot) is `School`:

```
string[] filteredValues = Array.FindAll(myValues, s => s.Split('.')[0] == myFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to make an IComparer that sorts the array by the matching value (if it contains filter return 1 else return 0) then find the first item outside the filter and make another array with the values up the one before that point.