# Loop through string and remove any occurrence of specified word

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach

I'm trying to remove all conjunctions and pronouns from any array of strings(let call that array A), The words to be removed are read from a text file and converted into an array of strings(lets call that array B).

What I need is to Get the first element of array A and compare it to every word in array B, if the word matches I want to delete the word of array A.

For example:

array A = [0]I [1]want [2]to [3]go [4]home [5]and [6]sleep
array B = [0]I [1]and [2]go [3]to

Result= array A = [0]want [1]home [2]sleep

```
//remove any duplicates,conjunctions and Pronouns
        public IQueryable<All_Articles> removeConjunctionsProNouns(IQueryable<All_Articles> myArticles)
        {
            //get words to be removed
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("A:\\EnterpriceAssigment\\EnterpriceAssigment\\TextFiles\\conjunctions&ProNouns.txt").ToLower();
            //split word into array of strings 
            string[] wordsToBeRemoved = text.Split(',');
            //all articles
            foreach (var article in myArticles)
            {
               //split articles into words
                string[] articleSplit = article.ArticleContent.ToLower().Split(' ');
                //loop through array of articles words
                foreach (var y in articleSplit)
                {
                    //loop through words to be removed from articleSplit
                    foreach (var x in wordsToBeRemoved)
                    {
                        //if word of articles matches word to be removed, remove word from article
                        if (y == x)
                        {
                            //get index of element in array to be removed
                            int g = Array.IndexOf(articleSplit,y);
                            //assign elemnt to ""
                            articleSplit[g] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //re-assign splitted article to string
                article.ArticleContent = articleSplit.ToString();
            }
            return myArticles;
        }
```

If it is possible as well, I need array A to have no duplicates/distinct values.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what about when the same word has more occurrence more than 1 will that remove all occurrence or just the first occurrence? and Iam working with string arrays not IEnumerable<TSource>

Comment: Arrays are IEnumerable. Except result is a distinct set of the source values not in the exception list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for IEnumerable.Except, where the passed parameter is applied to the input sequence and every element of the input sequence not present in the parameter list is returned *only once*

For example

```
string inputText = "I want this string to be returned without some words , but words should have only one occurence";
string[] excludedWords = new string[] {"I","to","be", "some", "but", "should", "have", "one", ","};

var splitted = inputText.Split(' ');
var result = splitted.Except(excludedWords);
foreach(string s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// ---- Output ----
want
this
string
returned
without
words   <<-- This appears only once
only
occurence
```

And applied to your code is:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(......).ToLower();
string[] wordsToBeRemoved = text.Split(',');
foreach (var article in myArticles)
{
    string[] articleSplit = article.ArticleContent.ToLower().Split(' ');
    var result = articleSplit.Except(wordsToBeRemoved);
    article.ArticleContent = string.Join(" ", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove **stop words**. You can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  ...
  string filePath = @"A:\EnterpriceAssigment\EnterpriceAssigment\TextFiles\conjunctions & ProNouns.txt";

  // Hashset is much more efficient than array in the context
  HashSet<string> stopWords = new HashSet<string>(File
    .ReadLines(filePath), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  foreach (var article in myArticles) {
    // read article, split into words, filter out stop words... 
    var cleared = article
      .ArticleContent
      .Split(' ')
      .Where(word => !stopWords.Contains(word));

    // ...and join words back into article
    article.ArticleContent = string.Join(" ", cleared);  
  }
  ...
```

Please, notice, that I've preserved `Split()` which you've used in your code and so you have a *toy implementation*. In real life you have at least to take *punctuation* into consideration, and that's why a better code uses *regular expressions*:

```
  foreach (var article in myArticles) {
    // read article, extract words, filter out stop words... 
    var cleared = Regex
      .Matches(article.ArticleContent, @"\w+") // <- extract words
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(match => match.Value)
      .Where(word => !stopWords.Contains(word));

    // ...and join words back into article
    article.ArticleContent = string.Join(" ", cleared);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your answer already in your code.  I am sure your code could be cleaned up a bit, as all our code could be.  You loop through articleSplit and pull out each word.  Then compare that word to the words in the wordsToBeRemoved array in a loop one by one.  You use your conditional to compare and when true you remove the items from your original array, or at least try.

I would create another array of the results and then display, use or what ever you'd like with the array minus the words to exclude. 
Loop through articleSplit
foreach x in arcticle split
    foreach y in wordsToBeRemoved
       if x != y newArray.Add(x)

However this is quite a bit of work.  You may want to use array.filter and then add that way.  There is a hundred ways to achieve this.

Here are some helpful articles:
[filter an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912128/filter-an-array-in-c-sharp) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx
These will save you from all that looping.